# IIS server is not working

Tags: iis

My webapp on IIS server is not working. I am trying to run my application on IIS and I am getting this error:

> ERROR
>   The requested URL could not be retrieved

Comment: What OS or version of IIS are you running? Is the app ASP or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Hai jyoti,

- Try restarting the server, or at
  least IIS.
- Double-check your virtual directory
  setup in the IIS management console.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have installed IIS server correctly... Re-installing the IIS server might fix the problem... Also check the version of the OS you use. Some versions of windows have compatibility problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the host header for the site you're trying to access specified correctly? Including with www. and without?